# Why do many of the methods in the Java API have "abstract" modifiers?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract

Student level question, I'm hoping stackOverflow can help me gain a deeper understanding here:

I've noticed that many of the methods (such as those in [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html), for example) in the Java API have "abstract" modifiers. Why is this?

I'm just wrapping my head around inheritance and polymorphism right now, but as I understand it, an abstract class is meant to be used as a kind of "parent class" that is extended by sub-classes, and that abstract classes themselves cannot be instantiated.

I also understand that abstract methods are declared (but not implemented) in an abstract class, and supposedly must be implemented within a subclass for that subclass to be considered non-abstract (and to therefore be instantiable).

So, how is it that I'm able to import a class like Graphics2D, create an instance of it and use its abstract methods?

My instructor mentioned something about the methods being overwritten at run-time (?), but I don't understand how/why. Obviously I'm missing something here, I'd love more insight!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So, how is it that I'm able to import a class like Graphics2D, create an instance of it and use its abstract methods?

Because you never create an instance of `Graphics2D` *directly*. Look at your code - you won't find this:

```
Graphics2D graphics = new Graphics2D(); // This wouldn't compile
```

... anywhere. Instead, you'll find calls to methods that *return* a `Graphics2D`, which are actually returning references to instances of concrete subclasses. Or maybe you'll provide methods which accept a `Graphics` or a `Graphics2D` parameter which the caller provides... and the caller *may* know about the concrete class, or they may have obtained a reference from elsewhere too.

In some ways, that's the whole point - the fact that you're even wondering where these subclasses are is proof about how well the whole thing is working... you only ever need to deal with `Graphics2D`, but the implementation details of that can differ by platform etc.

When your instructor was talking about methods being overwritten, I suspect they actually said *overridden* - where a subclass can provide a more specific implementation of a method than a superclass, or indeed may provide one where the superclass only has the abstract method declaration.

Comment: Great reply, thanks. It makes a lot of sense that some methods are returning instances of concrete, non-abstract subclasses, but what do you mean by "the caller may **know** about the concrete class"?

How would simple knowledge of the existence of an abstract superclass  help? Or, were you implying a different interpretation of "knowing" ?

Comment: The caller may know the concerete class because it is for example the graphicssubsystem. It basicallyconstructs and passes the concrete class, but you access it only abstractly. This is very much like a Interface. (the difference is only for the implementor)

Answer (score 1):

It's to keep the implementation separate from the definition; akin to C/C++ header files.

Let's think of some basic classes that we all use in Java, such as an `InputStream`. We know we'll need a way to read, so we define a couple of appropriate abstract methods, with no actual implementation yet.

This is beneficial to us, because if a class inherits from `InputStream`, we know that it will have implemented the read methods we defined originally. Usually these implementations differ sublcass to subclass.

For instance, let's think of a couple of subclassess of `InputStream`, like `GZIPInputStream`, and `FileInputStream`. `GZIPInputStream` will have to decompress bytes in its read calls. `FileInputStream` only has to read bytes from a file passed in its constructor. You can see where this is going.